# Date difference in JQuery received NAN

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to calculate the days on Blur method of End Date. But I received 'NAN'.What at could be wrong? I received 'NAN'.

```
$('#EndDate').blur(function () {

   var diff = dateDiff($('#StartDate').val(), $('#EndDate').val());
    alert(diff);

});

function dateDiff(startDate, endDate) {
    return endDate.getDate() - startDate.getDate();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.getDate()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-getDate) isn't defined for string objects (which is what [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) gives you), so you'll get 2 `undefined` variables trying to subtract one another battling it out, and `undefined - undefined === NaN`.

---

Instead, you need to get the date from both date pickers and subtract them like this:

```
$('#EndDate').blur(function () {
 var diff = dateDiff($('#StartDate').datepicker("getDate"), 
                     $('#EndDate').datepicker("getDate"));
 alert(diff);
});

function dateDiff(startDate, endDate) {
  if(endDate && startDate) //make sure we don't call .getTime() on a null
    return (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24);
  return "You must complete both dates!";
}
```

---

Also, instead of `blur`, I'd use the `onSelect` event provided, like this:

```
$('#EndDate').datepicker({
  onSelect: function() {
    var diff = dateDiff($('#StartDate').datepicker("getDate"), 
                        $('#EndDate').datepicker("getDate"));
    alert(diff);
  }
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/6Zdkn/1/).

Comment: I received "Object doesn't support" error message at endDate.getTime()

Comment: @nav100 - are you not using the jQuery UI datepicker? if not...what are you using, and I'm very confused by your question tags...

Comment: @nav100 - Ah, I was correcting your code as-is, you'll want additional checks in there, like `if(endDate && startDate)` in the `dateDiff` function to ensure you're not calling `.getTime()` on a null.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am using UI datepicker. I am getting End Date is null error message.

Comment: @nav100 - I updated the above code to show what a null check should look like, and the demo at the bottom as well.

Comment: Nick, I am not getting any alert message if I use onSelect. I am using TextBoxFor from MVC.

Comment: onBlur also not getting fired the first time. It works fine if I select the End Date again.

Comment: @nav100 - are you typing in the date or using the date picker?

Comment: @nav100 - do you have an example page?  You can see from my demo at the end of the answer it should work the first time.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
function calculate(start_date,end_date)         
{

  var t1= start_date ;

  var t2= end_date;

  // The number of milliseconds in one day

  var one_day=1000*60*60*24;

  //Here we need to split the inputed dates to convert them into standard format

  var x=t1.split(“/”);

  var y=t2.split(“/”);

  //date format(Fullyear,month,date)

  var date1=new Date(x[2],(x[1]-1),x[0]);

  var date2=new Date(y[2],(y[1]-1),y[0]);

  //Calculate difference between the two dates, and convert to days

  numberofDays=Math.ceil((date2.getTime()-date1.getTime())/(one_day));

  // numberofDays gives the diffrence between the two dates.

  $(‘#Input_type_text).val(numberofDays);

}
```